# Is it possible to add childs while keeping old ones using Firebase databse in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving coordinates from a list in Firebase using smartphone sensors. The X is being saved on a child called "Coordinate X" and Y on a child called "Coordinate Y". Both of these child are inside a child called "Path 1".

What I want is: everytime I run the app to add coordinates but in another child with the same name, like this -->

How it really is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMUQT.png)

How I want it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HagLR.png)

Right now, every time I run the app it overwrites the childs coordinates X and Y. Every time I run the app I want to add two more child "Coordinate X" and "Coordinate Y" with the new coordinates.
I tried using push() but it is hard to understand what is the new data and old data and it really didn't split the coordinates per app run.

I am sorry if I didn't explain well. Thank you!

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/qvgazm/is_it_possible_to_add_childs_while_keeping_old/

Answer (score 0):

Keys are by definition unique within their parent, so you can't have multiple child nodes named `Coordinate X` under a single parent.

The idiomatic approach for this is to create a list of uniquely named child nodes, by calling `push` for every set of coordinates.

If you're using the Android SDK (given that you tagged with Android), that'd be:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Path 1");
Map coordinates = new HashMap();
coordinates.put("X", 123);
coordinates.puth("Y", 456);
ref.push().setValue(coordinates);
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [reading and writing lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Comment: I end up changing the database setup according to what was asked by my teacher so I no longer needed to follow the that approach I was trying to implement! Thank you for answer anyways, however I tried but couldn't get the proper result. Thank you again!